# How common in general population sexual arousal towards children?

Tags: sexuality

What percentage of the general population have attraction to children (not teens) ?
Not how much are child molesters but how many feel attraction.
I will appreciate if you can give research in your comment.

Mode

Comment: Related: [At what age are women perceived to be most attractive?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/5509/7001)